# Why MS Word (MAC) is adding random white space?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

For a couple years now, Word randomly adds space between list elements/paragraphs/lines half way through a document, with no settings changed at all.

Any help is appreciated as its making Word borderline unusable when I have to copy/paste 20,000 word documents every 10 minutes to get rid of the issue.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fth9e.png]

Comment: What is the source of your copy? A website? Another word document?

Comment: Is there any macro code in the document? Does this problem exist in all file formats?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the line spacing has changed in the middle of the list. Try importing the *original* document into another word processor, such free [LibreOffice Writer](https://libreoffice.org/download/download), to see if the issue appears there, as well. If so, the document is at fault, but if not, it's MS Word to blame.